# Как получить погоду?

Tags: javascript, api, frontend

Делаю приложение по показу погоды(html, css, js) . Использую API openweathermap. Если задаю параметры показать на 24 часа, то показывает с настоящего времени и на период в течении 24 часов. т.е. если я отправляю запрос днем, то данные за утро уже не вижу. Как получить данные на сегодня (с утра до вечера)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Historical weather API там все есть, можешь получить погоду за конкретный день и конкретное время